# How to release a VMware unused license from a host? New licensing scheme?

Tags: licensing, vmware-vcenter

I own VMware Essentials license (6 CPU's)

One of the hosts is going to be replaced with a new one. I am having trouble removing/changing the license on that host.

[image]

As you can see on the image: the option to select the evaluation mode is grayed out for me.

How can I release that license?

EDIT: Removing the HOST from the VCenter - did not release the license for the CPU's. I want to point, that if I disconnect the server I CAN add a 3rd host to VCenter.

The new host is added to the VCenter - with evaluation key. But I can only see 1 CPU license available.

Is this somehow related to the changes that were done in the licensing scheme of VMWare Essentials?

---

VSphere editions [image]

-- # of licenses is wrong
[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. I restarted vCenter and the licensing became available Rob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disconnect the server and replace the server with a new host...

Or you can simply remove the host from the vCenter setup. E.g. disconnect the host from your centralized management. That will release the license.

[image]

It's possible that the number of available CPU's is NOT the correct number.
[image]

Comment: I don't think disconnecting the server from vCenter releases the license. It only disconnects the server from vCenter, but it (and it's assigned license) is still registered with vCenter.

Comment: It's been updated....

Comment: This did not work for me but I'm running ESXi 5.5u2. I removed it from vCenter and even applied a license for the free ESXi to it and vCenter still shows all 6 CPUs as in use.

Comment: @SteveHiner Call it in to support.

Comment: Actually it turns out that the description lacked one crucial step: Wait 30 minutes or more. After a while when I tried it in vCenter again the CPUs were available again. Must be that it takes a bit for the host to notify VMware that the license is no longer being used. To be clear, I did try it a couple times with a bit of time between so it wasn't like I expected it to be instantaneous.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the host from vCenter. This will "remove" the license from that host and make it available for your new host.

Comment: Thanks, but neither removing the host from the VCenter doesn't release the CPU's to use. (see edited Q)

Comment: What vSphere version are you running? I just did this in vSphere 4.1 and it worked exactly as I described.

Answer (score 0):

On vCenter Server Appliance 5.5, SSH into your Appliance and restart the VMware VirtualCenter Server Service AFTER removing the hosts. The licenses will then become available to reallocate.

Here is a link to a KB discussing the services:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2054085

Answer (score 0):

Enter the host into maintenance mode and remove from vCenter inventory, refresh (i'm using web client 6.0 U2) then select the (new) host -> Manage -> Licensing, license is now available.